# AWS neptune performance issue

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

I have approx 450k routes/paths in my AWS neptune, below is the sample for the graph I have

```
g.addV('vertex').as('1').
  property(single, 'orgId', 123).addV('vertex').
    as('2').
  property(single, 'orgId', 456).addV('vertex').
    as('3').
  property(single, 'orgId', 346).addV('vertex').
    as('4').
  property(single, 'orgId', 978).addV('vertex').
    as('5').
  property(single, 'compId', 1234).
  addV('vertex').as('6').
  property(single, 'compId', 7982).
  addV('vertex').as('7').
  property(single, 'compId', 9789).
  addV('vertex').as('8').
  property(single, 'compId', 9722).
  addV('vertex').as('9').
  property(single, 'compId', 8926).
  addV('vertex').as('10').
  property(single, 'orgId', 899).
  addE('service').from('1').to('5').
  addE('service').from('5').to('6').
  addE('service').from('6').to('3').
  addE('service').from('5').to('7').
  addE('service').from('7').to('2').
  addE('service').from('7').to('8').
  addE('service').from('8').to('4').
  addE('service').from('6').to('8').
  addE('service').from('5').to('8').
  addE('service').from('4').to('9').
  addE('service').from('3').to('9').
  addE('service').from('9').to('10')
```

Or we can go here to understand the structure https://gremlify.com/zxoso3go6we

Few important points on my graph structure

1. I am not using any labels for my vertexes.
2. All the vertex have same set of properties (above graph only contain the properties on which I query the graph)
3. Edges have label defined with value "service" (same is defined in the above graph)
4. I am using the t3.medium instance type.

Below are few queries I am running on regular basis

```
 graph.with(Tokens.ARGS_EVAL_TIMEOUT, 180000L).V().has("orgId", "123")
.repeat(outE("service").otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has("orgId", P.neq(StringUtils.EMPTY)));
```

I tried this query also without passing token.

**Problem** I am facing here is

1. Frequently getting Out of Memory. to tackle this I increase the POD JVM allocation to 5GB, but still facing this quite frequently. I am not sure if this is due to POD memory allocation or Neptune is throwing OOM. I tried analysing Heap Dump as well for my POD, but I didn't see any memory leaks.
2. Sometimes I face TimeLimitExceededException, that's why I tried passing the token at query level.
3. Second query I execute is, with or without using the token attribute

```
graph.V().has("compId", "6782").with(Tokens.ARGS_EVAL_TIMEOUT, 180000L).repeat(bothE("service").otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has("orgId", .neq(StringUtils.EMPTY)));
```

**Problem** with this query

1. I always get TimeLimitExceededExcaption.

Few thoughts I have in mind

1. Assign LABEL to vertexes, I can mark the vertexes as ORG where I have the value for property orgId, else I can mark it as REGULAR vertex.
2. Increase the instance size of my neptune, I guess that wuld help me in resolving TimeLimitExceededException at least, as I am not so sure about OOM exception.

**Questions**

1. I am open for any suggestions whether it is changing the query for better performance?
2. Did using LABELS on vertex will help, and use them in query?
3. Increase the instance type to get more computing power?
4. with(Tokens.ARGS_EVAL_TIMEOUT, 180000L) when we are passing the value for this Token, does this considered as millisecs or seconds, I am assuming its millisec, I guess 3 min is not a good time a query should take.

Below are some stats for the data, and `profile` output
Instance Size : db.r6g.large, with 2 vCPU and 16GB memory
Total vertex : 1130
Total edges : 150020

*Profile Output*

1. When running with `limit` 100 and 1000
   `

   awscurl --service neptune-db -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' https:///gremlin/profile -d '{"gremlin":"g.V().has("orgId","123").repeat(outE("service").otherV().simplePath()).until(**.has("orgId",P.neq(""))).path().by(**.valueMap()).limit(100)"}'

## Query String

```
g.V().has("orgId","123").repeat(outE("service").otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has("orgId",P.neq(""))).path().by(__.valueMap()).limit(100)
```

## Original Traversal

```
[GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([orgId.eq(123)]), RepeatStep([VertexStep(OUT,[service],edge), EdgeOtherVertexStep, PathFilterStep(simple,null,null), RepeatEndStep],until([HasStep([orgId.neq()])]),emit(false)), PathStep([[PropertyMapStep(value)]]), RangeGlobalStep(0,100)]
```

## Optimized Traversal

```
Neptune steps:
[
    NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex) {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[(?1, <orgId>, "123", <~>) . project ?1 .], {estimatedCardinality=20, expectedTotalInput=-1, expectedTotalOutput=20, indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=20}
            RepeatNode {
                Repeat {
                    JoinGroupNode {
                        PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<service>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?7,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .], {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=84870, expectedTotalInput=-1, indexTime=0, joinTime=2, numSearches=3}
                        SimplePathFilter(?1, ?7, ?4)) .
                    }
                }
                Until {
                    PatternNode[(?4, <orgId>, ?9, ?) . project ask . ContainsFilter(?9 not in ("")) .], {hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=1130, expectedTotalInput=-1, indexTime=1, joinTime=0}
                }
            }, inputVar=?1, outputVar=?10, leftVar=?3, rightVar=?4, annotations={emitFirst=false, untilFirst=false, repeatMode=BFS}
        }, finishers=[limit(100)], {path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Edge(?7,?3,?4):VertexStep, Vertex(?4):EdgeOtherVertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶1̶0̶)̶:̶E̶d̶g̶e̶O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶]], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=2, maxVarId=17, executionTime=28}
    },
    NeptunePathStep {
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?1, ?11, ?12, <~>) . CompareFilter(?11 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        },
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?7, ?13, ?14, <~>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        },
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?4, ?15, ?16, <~>) . CompareFilter(?15 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        }
    },
    NeptuneTraverserConverterStep
]
```

## Physical Pipeline

```
NeptuneGraphQueryStep
    |-- StartOp
    |-- JoinGroupOp@15a0bbb7
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@47abfacc(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, <orgId>, "123", <~>) . project ?1 .], {estimatedCardinality=20, expectedTotalInput=-1, expectedTotalOutput=20}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(100, @47abfacc, null)
        |-- RepeatOp
            |-- <upstream input> (Iteration 0) [visited=20, output=0 (until=0, emit=0), next=20]
            |-- BindingSetQueue (Iteration 1) [visited=407, output=100 (until=100, emit=0), next=307]
                |-- JoinGroupOp@575e22d5
                    |-- DynamicJoinOp@45e2ca1c(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<service>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?7,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .], {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=84870, expectedTotalInput=-1}))
                    |-- FilterOp(SimplePathFilter(?1, ?7, ?4)) .)
        |-- LimitOp(100)

NeptunePathStep
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@38e51f47
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@10a27b53(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, ?11, ?12, <~>) . CompareFilter(?11 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@fd8c57d
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@40c31285(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?7, ?13, ?14, <~>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@504c22fd
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@53b7a344(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, ?15, ?16, <~>) . CompareFilter(?15 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
```

## Runtime (ms)

Query Execution: 28.347

## Traversal Metrics

Step                           Count Traversers  Time (ms)  %Dur
NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)   100   100        4.212     15.24
NeptunePathStep([[NeptuneP..    100   100        20.306    73.47
NeptuneTraverserConverterStep   100   100         3.122    11.30

> TOTAL                          -     -          27.641     -

## Repeat Metrics

### Iteration  Visited   Output    Until     Emit     Next

```
    0       20        0     0        0       20
    1      407      100    100        0      307
```

---

```
           427      100    100        0      327
```

## Predicates

## of predicates: 12

## Results

Count: 100

## Index Operations

Query execution:
# of statement index ops: 206
# of unique statement index ops: 206
Duplication ratio: 1.0
# of terms materialized: 0

*For limit 1000*

---

```
            Neptune Gremlin Profile
```

---

## Query String

```
g.V().has("orgId","123").repeat(outE("service").otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has("orgId",P.neq(""))).path().by(__.valueMap()).limit(1000)
```

## Original Traversal

```
[GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([orgId.eq(123)]), RepeatStep([VertexStep(OUT,[service],edge), EdgeOtherVertexStep, PathFilterStep(simple,null,null), RepeatEndStep],until([HasStep([orgId.neq()])]),emit(false)), PathStep([[PropertyMapStep(value)]]), RangeGlobalStep(0,1000)]
```

## Optimized Traversal

```
Neptune steps:
[
    NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex) {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[(?1, <orgId>, "123", <~>) . project ?1 .], {estimatedCardinality=20, expectedTotalInput=-1, expectedTotalOutput=20, indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=20}
            RepeatNode {
                Repeat {
                    JoinGroupNode {
                        PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<service>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?7,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .], {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=84870, expectedTotalInput=-1, indexTime=0, joinTime=18, numSearches=19}
                        SimplePathFilter(?1, ?7, ?4)) .
                    }
                }
                Until {
                    PatternNode[(?4, <orgId>, ?9, ?) . project ask . ContainsFilter(?9 not in ("")) .], {hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=1130, expectedTotalInput=-1, indexTime=1, joinTime=1}
                }
            }, inputVar=?1, outputVar=?10, leftVar=?3, rightVar=?4, annotations={emitFirst=false, untilFirst=false, repeatMode=BFS}
        }, finishers=[limit(1000)], {path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Edge(?7,?3,?4):VertexStep, Vertex(?4):EdgeOtherVertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶1̶0̶)̶:̶E̶d̶g̶e̶O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶]], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=2, maxVarId=17, executionTime=195}
    },
    NeptunePathStep {
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?1, ?11, ?12, <~>) . CompareFilter(?11 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        },
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?7, ?13, ?14, <~>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        },
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?4, ?15, ?16, <~>) . CompareFilter(?15 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}
            }, {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?7=null, ?10=null}}
        }
    },
    NeptuneTraverserConverterStep
]
```

## Physical Pipeline

```
NeptuneGraphQueryStep
    |-- StartOp
    |-- JoinGroupOp@2f682c6a
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@7a123125(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, <orgId>, "123", <~>) . project ?1 .], {estimatedCardinality=20, expectedTotalInput=-1, expectedTotalOutput=20}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @7a123125, null)
        |-- RepeatOp
            |-- <upstream input> (Iteration 0) [visited=20, output=0 (until=0, emit=0), next=20]
            |-- BindingSetQueue (Iteration 1) [visited=4421, output=1000 (until=1000, emit=0), next=3421]
                |-- JoinGroupOp@6327ca4c
                    |-- DynamicJoinOp@31ad6221(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<commercialService>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?7,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .], {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=84870, expectedTotalInput=-1}))
                    |-- FilterOp(SimplePathFilter(?1, ?7, ?4)) .)
        |-- LimitOp(1000)

NeptunePathStep
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@5fc81302
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@34389ac7(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, ?11, ?12, <~>) . CompareFilter(?11 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@691043a6
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@33f698cf(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?7, ?13, ?14, <~>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@2cb9cdb0
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@5ca78442(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, ?15, ?16, <~>) . CompareFilter(?15 != <~label>) .], {expectedTotalInput=-1}))
```

## Runtime (ms)

Query Execution: 196.337

## Traversal Metrics

Step                              Count  Traversers Time (ms) % Dur
NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)      1000  1000        32.697   16.86
NeptunePathStep([[Nept...          1000  1000       125.653   64.78
NeptuneTraverserConverterStep      1000  1000       35.617    18.36

> TOTAL                             -     -         193.969        -

## Repeat Metrics

### Iteration  Visited   Output    Until     Emit     Next

```
    0       20        0      0        0       20
    1     4421     1000     1000        0     3421
```

---

```
          4441     1000     1000        0     3441
```

## Predicates

## of predicates: 12

## Results

Count: 1000

## Index Operations

Query execution:
# of statement index ops: 1253
# of unique statement index ops: 1252
Duplication ratio: 1.00
# of terms materialized: 0

Comment: The [tag:graphdb] tag is for a specific product (Ontotext GraphDB), which you don’t seem to use. (I can’t edit your question to remove it, because the queue is full.)

Comment: The sample code to build the graph appears to be missing at least one line. When a timeout is specified at the query level it cannot exceed the timeout already specified at the cluster/instance level. A T3 medium is a small instance type. When you have a decent amount of data to work with a larger instance will give you more RAM/CPU. You might also want to look at using a serverless instance type. In general I would always use meaningful vertex labels, they are useful for filtering. Also the ID can be any string of your choosing. So using meaningful IDs from your domain can help.

Comment: I took a look at this further, but noticed in your sample graph the orgId properties have integer values but in the query you are testing them as strings. Assuming they are meant to be strings I modified the creation steps and loaded them that way. Over the sample graph the queries seem to run fine. When you run the queries against your actual graph, how much data are they touching? It would be worth getting a `/profile` for the query if possible (after extending the timeout or maybe adding a `limit` to make sure the query can complete).

Comment: In general using labels can be helpful both in allowing queries to filter more aggressively and also when visualizing results it's easier to group/color etc. by label if they are not all the same (the default label will be 'vertex')

Comment: @KelvinLawrence
I tried `/profile` with `limit`, below are some findings
1. Now I am using db.r6g.large instance which has 2 vCPU and 16GB memory.
2. From the `/profile` output I am seeing Query Execution time is increasing linearly, as I increase the `limit`.
3. I have total vertex 1130 and total edges 150020.

If I ran the `/profile` without limit, I am getting  MemoryLimitExceededException.

Comment: If you are able to share the profile here that would be very helpful. If you are not able to share it can you open an AWS support case and share the profile with the support engineers? It sounds like the query is fanning out and touching a lot of data, which even with `simplePath` in place can still happen if the graph is highly connected. The profile is the best way to investigate this further.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I updated the `profile` output, also when I ran the above query without `limit` I am getting TimeLimitExceededException, on multiple runs it start giving MemoryExceedException as well

Comment: Thanks for adding these. Is it possible when you raise the limit, that even with `simplePath` present, it may be really hard to reach a node where the `orgId` is not an empty string? That would be the most likely explanation here I think. Is the data highly connected? Is it also possible in the data itself that that property could be missing on some nodes? This feels like what one might loosely call a "runaway" query where at some point the search for a non empty string node is taking essentially "forever".

Comment: In general, how deep into the graph would you expect each query to have to go? We could try adding a `loops()` check perhaps?

Comment: Yes my data is highly connected, as I have only 1130 vertexs, total routes/paths is around 423000. I am sure of that the property `orgId` is not missing, it may not have any value which we represent with emptyString. I can not use `loops()` as I am not sure how deep i need to go. Can raising the instance compute power help us ??

Comment: Also tried `g.withSideEffect("Neptune#repeatMode", "DFS")` it also doesn't help

Comment: Instance size can sometimes help as it gives the query more memory to work with. You could also perhaps try `ChunkedDFS` - that "fan out" is quite big so likely explains what you are seeing. You seem to essentially be running an "all possible paths" query.