# Neptune Multi-AZ Cluster deployment throws Decompression Exception

Tags: tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

I am trying to get `paths()` from AWS neptune, using the below query on below graph

```
g.addV('ORG').as('1').
  property(single, 'orgId', 'f5c').addV('COMP').
    as('2').
  property(single, 'compId', 2112896).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('3').
  property(single, 'compId', 2100198).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('4').
  property(single, 'compId', 4007384).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('5').
  property(single, 'compId', 2106827).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('6').
  property(single, 'compId', 2106829).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('7').
  property(single, 'compId', 2104080).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('8').
  property(single, 'compId', 2110851).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('ORG').
    as('9').
  property(single, 'orgId', 28932).addE('edge').
  from('1').to('5').property('sub', '951a').
  addE('edge').from('1').to('2').
  property('sub', 5779).addE('edge').from('2').
  to('3').property('sub', 5779).addE('edge').
  from('3').to('4').property('sub', 5779).
  addE('edge').from('5').to('6').
  property('sub', '951a').addE('edge').
  from('6').to('7').property('sub', '951a').
  addE('edge').from('7').to('8').
  property('sub', '951a').addE('edge').
  from('4').to('9').property('sub', 1234).
  addE('edge').from('8').to('9').
  property('sub', 465474)
```

Query

```
g.V().has("orgId", "f5c")
.repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG")).path().by(valueMap())
```

Everything works fine when Neptune is running as Single Instance, but in one of the environment I have deployed Neptune as Cluster with Multi-AZ.
In this particular env, when I try to fetch `paths()` using the query above, I encountered below excpetion, and Neptune Engine version is 1.2.1.0

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-04-25T12:02:26.652Z",
  "@version": "1",
  "message": "Could not process the response",
  "logger_name": "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler",
  "thread_name": "gremlin-driver-loop-1",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "level_value": 40000,
  "stack_trace": "io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: decompression failure\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:276)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\n\tat io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.writeInbound(EmbeddedChannel.java:344)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.DeflateDecoder.decompressContent(DeflateDecoder.java:119)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.DeflateDecoder.decode(DeflateDecoder.java:80)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.PerMessageDeflateDecoder.decode(PerMessageDeflateDecoder.java:87)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.PerMessageDeflateDecoder.decode(PerMessageDeflateDecoder.java:31)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back
  at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:243)\n\t... 45 common frames omitted\n"
}{
  "@timestamp": "2023-04-25T12:02:26.66Z",
  "@version": "1",
  "message": "io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: decompression failure",
  "logger_name": "com.osttra.csm.route.exception.RouteControllerAdvice",
  "thread_name": "http-nio-8090-exec-1",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "level_value": 40000,
  "stack_trace": "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: decompression failure\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:123)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:175)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:169)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:100)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.fill(Traversal.java:184)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.toList(Traversal.java:122)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.service.impl.NeptuneServiceImpl.getRoutes(NeptuneServiceImpl.java:453)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.service.impl.NeptuneServiceImpl.getOrganisationRoutes(NeptuneServiceImpl.java:466)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.service.impl.NeptuneServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bf548975.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54)\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.service.impl.NeptuneServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4cf2f40e.getOrganisationRoutes(<generated>)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.contoller.RouteController.getOrganisationRoutes(RouteController.java:100)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.contoller.RouteController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$245b733d.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.contoller.RouteController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ad6b893.getOrganisationRoutes(<generated>)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:83)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat com.osttra.csm.route.config.JWTFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: decompression failure\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:276)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\n\tat io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.writeInbound(EmbeddedChannel.java:344)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.DeflateDecoder.decompressContent(DeflateDecoder.java:119)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.DeflateDecoder.decode(DeflateDecoder.java:80)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.PerMessageDeflateDecoder.decode(PerMessageDeflateDecoder.java:87)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.compression.PerMessageDeflateDecoder.decode(PerMessageDeflateDecoder.java:31)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236)\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)\n\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\t... 1 common frames omitted
  Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back
  at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:243)\n\t... 45 common frames omitted\n"
}
```

Note : I have large amount of data in this environment
Below are few dependencies I am using to connect with Neptune

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Sig4 dependency is used to connect with cluster like below

```
public Cluster cluster() {
        return Cluster.build(neptuneUrl).port(portNo).enableSsl(true).handshakeInterceptor(r -> {
            try {
                NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer sigV4Signer = new NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer(neptuneRegion,
                        new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
                sigV4Signer.signRequest(r);
            } catch (NeptuneSigV4SignerException e) {
                log.error("** Error while signing the request ** " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return r;
        }).maxConnectionPoolSize(10).minConnectionPoolSize(5).maxInProcessPerConnection(3).minSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(1)
                .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(3)
                .create();

    }
```

Slow query logs are coming for same below query, stats in the comment section

```
"queryStats": {
        "query": "g.V().has(\"orgId\",\"abc\").repeat(__.bothE(\"service\").otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has(\"orgId\",P.neq(\"\"))).path().by(__.valueMap())",
        "queryFingerprint": "g.V().has(string0,string1).repeat(__.bothE(string2).otherV().simplePath()).until(__.has(string0,P.neq(string3))).path().by(__.valueMap())",
        "queryLanguage": "Gremlin"
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the Neptune Slow Query Log feature enabled on that cluster?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Yes its ENABLED

Comment: Query in the description
`
  "queryTimeStats": {
        "startTime": "21/04/2023 10:44:55.104",
        "overallRunTimeMs": 9022
    }
 "queryTimeStats": {
        "startTime": "24/04/2023 10:33:12.658",
        "overallRunTimeMs": 39845
    } "queryTimeStats": {
        "startTime": "25/04/2023 11:59:36.855",
        "overallRunTimeMs": 169790
    }
`

Comment: @KelvinLawrence as per discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887171/aws-neptune-performance-issue
I am trying this on bigger instance type

Comment: Please try disabling the Slow Query Log and see if the decompression exception goes away.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence DISABLED logging still getting the same exception

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Are you able to open an AWS support case for this one? I think it may need some deeper investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Posting what we did to get around this issue, this is not exactly a solution
So basically we were getting this Decompression Exception when we upgraded to cluster deployment with Neptune Engine version 1.2.1.0, later we downgrade to version 1.1.1.0, after that we never encountered the exception.